# Experimental/private branch for OID numbers in LDAP Schemas?

Tags: ldap, snmp, oid

Attributes or object classes in LDAP schemas are identified through a unique number called [OID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier). Moreover OIDs are also used in the SNMP protocol. Everyone can apply for an [enterprise number by the IANA](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) and then define his own subnumbers. But the processing of the application can last up to 30 days.

Does anyone know if there is a "test" branch of OID numbers that could be used for experimental purposes while waiting for an official enterprise number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the OID branch 2.25 can be used with UUIDs without registration.
The detailled explanation can be found here:
http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.25 and there is also a link to an UUID generator.

=> I think it's good solution for unregistered OIDs. Simply generate one such OID with the UUID-Generator. You will get something like 2.25.178307330326388478625988293987992454427 and can then simply make your own subnumbers by adding .1, .2, ... at the end.

There is also the possibility to register such an 2.25 OID, but a human intervention is still needed and uniqueness isn't totally garanteed as it is still possible (although unlikely) that someone else uses the same OID as unregistered OID. For registered OIDs I would still prefer the registration of a private entreprise number by the IANA.

Here is also a list of how to get an OID assigned: http://www.oid-info.com/faq.htm#10. But the main answers are already listed here.

Answer (score 4):

No. However, if there is nothing published from your work no one will know.
Some LDAP server companies will sub OID numbers if you wanted to try something. But you could just makeup anything.

The currently assigned numbers only start with 0, 1, or 2. If you started with 4 or something, any savey person would know you were faking it.

We put some info together on OIDs here:
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/HowToGetYourOwnLDAPOID

-jim

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Starting with 4 would be a good trick but the Apache Directory Studio Schema Editor doesn't allow OIDs starting with 4 (just 0, 1 or 2). Currently I'm using a random number (starting with 1) but it would be nicer to have a private test branch.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you're based. In the UK, each company gets it's own OID branch to play with as it will http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.826.0

(Not sure if there are similar setups in other countries

Comment: Thanks for the link but as far as I see, it is something similar to the IANA private entreprise numbers (http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page).

Comment: Except it's automatic - if your a registered company in the UK, your company number forms part of your private branch.

Comment: Then it is a nice solution for companies based in the UK! Unfortunately it won't work for me.

Comment: Australia has a similar thing with 1.2.36.[ACN] - see http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.36.html (similarly, http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.826.0.html might provide a more readable description for the UK)